# How to programmatically change the background color of a button

Tags: java, android, android-button

I am using Android Studio and would like to use the colors.xml file to change the background color of a button `btn`. Both of these work for me:

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlue, null));
```

and

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorBlue));
```

Which one is better? I guess better means faster and consuming less memory/cpu usage.

Comment: Question title and question description is irrelevant.

Comment: @ARiF Yes that works, but it's not getting a color that I defined in colors.xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `setBackgroundResource` method which accepts the resource id as a parameter.

Comment: That works. It is certainly shorter and looks better.

Answer (score 3):

This code is changing color of AppCompatButton

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_orange_light), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.

Comment: It solves the issue because of it's code. Question needs answer of code, not explanation in this case.